# Robot class right click then left click issues

Tags: java

I've got this code, when I only have the right click, it right clicks, but when I add the left click the right click doesn't want to happen, only the left click.. 
Can anyone explain this?

```
        public void drop(){
          mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
          mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
          mouseMove(x-35,y+35);
          mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
          mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        }
```

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't give any delay, silly mistake

Answer (score 2):

How do you recognise that right click didn't happen? Try to use delays between mouse actions like this:

```
void drop() {
    mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
    delay(100);
    mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
    mouseMove(x - 35, y + 35);
    mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    delay(100);
    mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
}
```